# Kubernetes node ulimit settings

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running Kubernets v1.11.1 cluster, sometime my kube-apiserver server started throwing the 'too many open files' message. I noticed to many open TCP connections node kubelet port 10250

My server configured with 65536 file descriptors. Do I need to increase the number of open files for the container host? What are the recommended ulimit settings for the container host?

**api server log message**

```
I1102 13:57:08.135049       1 logs.go:49] http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:6443: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s
I1102 13:57:09.135191       1 logs.go:49] http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:6443: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s
I1102 13:57:10.135437       1 logs.go:49] http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:6443: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s
I1102 13:57:11.135589       1 logs.go:49] http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:6443: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s
I1102 13:57:12.135755       1 logs.go:49] http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:6443: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s
```

my host ulimit values:

```
# ulimit -a
-f: file size (blocks)             unlimited
-t: cpu time (seconds)             unlimited
-d: data seg size (kb)             unlimited
-s: stack size (kb)                8192
-c: core file size (blocks)        unlimited
-m: resident set size (kb)         unlimited
-l: locked memory (kb)             64
-p: processes                      unlimited
-n: file descriptors               65536
-v: address space (kb)             unlimited
-w: locks                          unlimited
-e: scheduling priority            0
-r: real-time priority             0
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: this not help? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67004#issuecomment-410617090

Comment: @DenisA. I saw this only as you can see my kube ai server already running with 65535 value for open files.

Comment: @sfgroups yes but as DenisA pointed out the limit can be defined as a systemd process limit different that the one set globally by ulimit on your system. Can you double check on that precise point ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`65536` seems a bit low, although there are many apps that recommend that number. This is what I have on one K8s cluster for the kube-apiserver:

```
# kubeapi-server-container
#  |
# \|/
# ulimit -a
-f: file size (blocks)             unlimited
-t: cpu time (seconds)             unlimited
-d: data seg size (kb)             unlimited
-s: stack size (kb)                8192
-c: core file size (blocks)        unlimited
-m: resident set size (kb)         unlimited
-l: locked memory (kb)             16384
-p: processes                      unlimited
-n: file descriptors               1048576 <====
-v: address space (kb)             unlimited
-w: locks                          unlimited
-e: scheduling priority            0
-r: real-time priority             0
```

Different from a regular bash process system limits:

```
# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15447
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024 <===
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15447
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

But yet the total max of the whole system:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
394306
```

If you see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/122679/how-do-ulimit-n-and-proc-sys-fs-file-max-differ) nothing can exceed `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` on the system, so I would also check that value. I would also check the number of file descriptors being used (first column), this will give you an idea of how many open files you have:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
2176    0   394306
```

Comment: Thanks Rico, I just looked Atomic OS, it set like this: `LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity`